# Compute weighted histogram using two DataArrays with different dimensions

Tags: python, python-xarray

I've been trying to compute a weighted histogram using two xarray DataArrays, but I've been having trouble doing it.

The way I see it, the best way to do it generally is to using `axr.apply_ufunc`, but I'm having trouble understanding how to use that function due to (in my opinion) poor documentation. As example, consider these two arrays:

```
arr1 = xr.DataArray(np.random.randn(5,5,5,), dims=("x", "y", "z"))
arr2 = xr.DataArray(np.random.randn(5,5,5,5), dims=("x", "y", "z", "f"))
```

I want to compute the histogram of `arr1` in the dimensions `x` and `y` weighted by `arr2` in the same dimensions. Thus we would have one histogram for every combination of `z` and `f`. So the final product would be something with dimensions `("z", "f", "bin_dim")`, where `bin_dim` is of course an extra dimension that's created with the size of the bin array.

The way I understand that it should be done is by doing this:

```
def hist_1d(a, w):
    return np.histogram(a, weights=w,)[0]

xr.apply_ufunc(hist_1d, arr1, arr2, input_core_dims=[["x", "y"], ["x", "y"]], output_core_dims=[["bin_dim"]])
```

But obviously I'm wrong because I get: `ValueError: weights should have the same shape as a.` I've been trying a couple of different options but always with an error that I can't understand.

Is there a way to do this using with xarray? I'd like to do it in a general way because, although I'll always apply this in dimensions `x` and `y` of my data, their order and the extra dimensions may change.

Cheers

**EDIT**

One thing that I tried that I think *almost* solves it is below

```
b1, b2, = xr.broadcast(arr1, arr2)
xr.apply_ufunc(hist_1d, b1, b2, input_core_dims=[["x", "y"], ["x", "y"]],)
```

But I think I'm getting some of the arguments wrong because I get `ValueError: applied function returned data with unexpected number of dimensions: 1 vs 2, for dimensions ('z', 'f')`.

Comment: I am having a lot of trouble trying to understand the question. `np.histogram` performs the histogram of the flattened array, so the desired output is a histogram binning values of `x` and `y` at the same time? Also, how should the combinations of `z` and `f` be done, by index? Or by value? I think it would be really helpful if you could add some kind of function to get the desired output (even if it is totally _unpythonic_) so we can compare.

Comment: About the error messages, the first error is from `np.histogram`, because the flattened lengths of `arr1` and `arr2` are different, so one cannot be used as the other. The second error is from `apply_ufunc` because it expects to receive something compatible with a `DataArray` with dims `z` and `f`, and it gets a 1D array instead. I suspect that what you are trying to achieve is not what `apply_ufunc` is designed for.

Comment: for anyone stumbling on this these days... [xhistogram](https://xhistogram.readthedocs.io/) is a great option